# Derivative of a piecewise function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 &\text{if $x$ is rational} \\ 0 &\text{if $x$ is irrational} \end{cases}$,
>
> $Q(h)=f(h)/h$ if $h \neq 0$.
>
> a) Prove $Q(h)\rightarrow 0$ as $h\rightarrow 0$, b) Prove that $f$ has a derivative at 0, and find $f'(0)$

This is how I tried to solve the first part:

Let $x \rightarrow 0$:

If  $x$ is irrational,$f(x) = 0$ and for rational $x$, $f(x) = 0$ (since $x \rightarrow 0$).

How would I prove the second part?

Comment: You could evaluate the derivatives of each piece of $f(x)$ and show that they are equal when $x=0$.

Comment: @Myridium it's not actually a piecewise function as you'd expect, your hint doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you haven't really done $Q(h) \rightarrow 0$ properly

write $Q(x) = \begin{cases} x &\text{if $x$ is rational} \\ 0 &\text{if $x$ is irrational} \end{cases}$

then note $|Q(x)| \le |x|$ so it must tend to $0$ at $0$

the other part is just noticing that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}Q(h)$ is the definition of $f'(0)$

Answer (score 1):

I would remark that
$$
f'(0)=\lim_{h \to 0} Q(h)=0,
$$
as you already proved.